RestEase - how to implement the deserialization of an Array of Results
I am a novice C# coder trying to use RestEase to call a RestAPI that returns an array e.g.[{"name":"value"}, {"name2":"value2"}] rather than a single {"name":"value"} response as per the Quick Start example code provided at https://github.com/canton7/RestEase?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start
If I change the Quickstart code to remove the /{userId} from [Get("users/{userId}")] I get an array of users rather than a single user, which causes this error

JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
(e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DemoApi.User' because the type requires a
JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix
this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
{"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
deserialize from a JSON array.

Please help with the syntax to accommodate this response in the context of the example provided in the RestEase example code here https://github.com/canton7/RestEase?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start.
Many thanks in advance
Alain
I've tried the suggested types but my syntax is clearly not correct e.g. (e.g. ICollection, IList)
Below is my edit version of the sample code that produces the error
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestEase;

namespace RestEaseSampleApplication
{
    // We receive a JSON response, so define a class to deserialize the json into
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Blog { get; set; }

        // This is deserialized using Json.NET, so use attributes as necessary
        [JsonProperty("created_at")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }

    // Define an interface representing the API
    // GitHub requires a User-Agent header, so specify one
    [Header("User-Agent", "RestEase")]
    public interface IGitHubApi
    {
        // The [Get] attribute marks this method as a GET request
        // The "users" is a relative path the a base URL, which we'll provide later
        // "{userId}" is a placeholder in the URL: the value from the "userId" method parameter is used
        [Get("users")]
        Task<User> GetUserAsync();
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an implementation of that interface
            // We'll pass in the base URL for the API
            IGitHubApi api = RestClient.For<IGitHubApi>("https://api.github.com");

            // Now we can simply call methods on it
            // Normally you'd await the request, but this is a console app
            User user = api.GetUserAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user.Name}. Blog: {user.Blog}. CreatedAt: {user.CreatedAt}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


I pretty much got stuck at this point. However I signed up for Github Co-Pilot and received an alternative solution using HttpClient. Github Copilot is a life-saver for novice coders, I'm sure I would have given up without its help.
